# bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker in a list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I finally got eonasdan bootstrap 3 datetimepicker to work on a form view of MVC 5. However, I am having trouble to get it to work on list view. Below is the codes I got. On the list view, clicking on the calendar field doesn't bring up the calendar. What am I missing? Any help?

Form View:

```
<div class="input-group date">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ActivateDate, new { @class = "form-group" })
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
           $('#ActivateDate').datetimepicker();
     });
</script>
```

List View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr class="orderedrow">
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].ServiceName, "Edit", new { Model[i].ServiceID })</td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group date">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].ActivateDate, new { @class = "form-group" })
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(function () {
                       $('#[@i].ActivateDate').datetimepicker();
                  });
            </script>
        </td>
    <tr>
}
```

Below is the html generated by the for loop above

```
<td>
    <div class="input-group date">
         <input class="form-group" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Activate Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Activate Date field is required." name="[12].ActivateDate" type="text" value="2/25/2015 12:00:00 AM" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#[12].ActivateDate').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
</td>
```

Per Sam's suggestion I changed the above code to this. But it still doesn't popup the calendar as I click on the Activate Date textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr class="orderedrow">
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].ServiceName, "Edit", new { Model[i].ServiceID })</td>
        <td>
            <div class="datetimepicker date">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].ActivateDate, new { @class = "form-group" })
            </div>
        </td>
    <tr>
}
```

Generated Html

```
<tr>
<td><a href="/someurl/admin?ServiceID=26">Cognos 10</a></td>
<td>
    <div class="datetimepicker date">
        <input class="form-group" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Activate Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Activate Date field is required." name="[34].ActivateDate" type="text" value="2/25/2015 12:00:00 AM" />
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors? I'm assuming you've included `moment` and the datepicker's js and css.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are invalid characters for an id: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

You could try escaping the square brackets in your datetimepicker selector.

Another way you could work around this issue is by assigning the same class to each datetimepicker (say class="datetimepicker"), then calling $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();, then you only need to make one call to initialize every picker.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ID issue. I also made some changes per your suggestion to move the jquery code to the <script /> section and calling  $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker(); but there's still no calendar pop-up like in the form view. Any other suggestion?

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#no-icon-input-field-only There he puts his selector on the actual input element. Also check the console and make sure you're not getting any javascript errors.

Comment: I tried that too. I had the code to generate the <input id="ActivateDate_0"...>. Then the javascript goes $('#ActivateDate_0').datetimepicker(); but that still does not work. I'm now confused how the bootstrap datetimepicker works.